# Laravel setup on HostGator VPS

Tags: laravel, deployment

I want to deploy my Laravel App in a VPS hosting plan.

I have a WHM, but I've no experience deploying my app and configure the server.

I don't have a domain, so I want to test my app using an IP address (like DigitalOcean)

any help?

Edit:

- I've completed these steps into my WHM.

1. Have SSH access to the VPS
2. Have a `sudo` user and set up some kind of firewall (for example `ufw`)
3. Install required software (`nginx`, `MySQL`, `PHP`, `Composer`, `npm`) and additional PHP modules if necessary.

- I've created an account ( CPanel ) and I've completed steps

4. Create a database
5. Checkout your application using `VCS` like `Git`
6. Configure your `.env` file.
7. Install your composer packages, run npm, or anything you would like to do

The account ( CPanel provides an IP address that looks like [http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/~cpanel-account-name/](http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/%7Ecpanel-account-name/)).
I can access the website correctly ( however all images are broken and even laravel-routes are not found 404). I know the issue is because ( ~cpanel-account-name/ ) found at the end of the URL.
But how can I fix It?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is quite a broad topic that consists of multiple questions, perhaps you could elaborate on steps you have already taken or the step you are stuck at / need help with?

In short, you need to do the following:

1. Have SSH access to the VPS
2. Have a `sudo` user and set-up some kind of firewall (for example `ufw`)
3. Install required software (`nginx`, `MySQL`, `PHP`, `Composer`, `npm`) and additional PHP modules if necessary.
4. Create a database
5. Checkout your application using `VCS` like `Git`
6. Configure your `.env` file.
7. Install your composer packages, run npm or anything you would like to do
8. Set-up `nginx`

If this seems daunting, I would advice to tackle it one by one and trying to research every step along the way. This might be challenging and time-consuming, but will be very rewarding!

Alternatively, a paid solution like [Laravel Forge](https://forge.laravel.com/) can help you take care of server management.

Comment: If you visit the ip address, are you immediately redirect to the `~cpanel-account-name/`?

Are you using Apache or Nginx?

Unfortunately, I have no experience using HostGator. Generally I run servers on DigitalOcean.

Comment: Yes. 
Apache.
No problem, Actually digitalOcean is much easier, but currently my client wants to deploy it into HostGator. Thank you for listing these steps.